How to highlight rows based on 2 columns that are duplicates?
I have a excel spreadsheet of all the software on all my systems.
I want to compare what is installed and what versions are different.
> Hostname        Software        Version
> servera           GConf2.x86_64   3.2.6-22.el8
> servera           MFEcma.x86_64   5.8.1-313
> servera           MFEdx.x86_64    6.0.3-1021
> servera           MFErt.i686      2.0-193
> servera           McAfeeESP.x86_64        10.7.17-487
> servera           McAfeeESPAac.x86_64     10.7.17-487
> servera           McAfeeESPFileAccess.x86_64      10.7.17-487
> servera           McAfeeFW.x86_64 10.7.17-50
> servera           McAfeeRt.x86_64 10.7.17-487
> servera           McAfeeTP.x86_64 10.7.17-66
> servera           NetworkManager.x86_64   1:1.40.16-9.el8_8
> serverb           GConf2.x86_64   3.2.6-22.el8
> serverb           MFEcma.x86_64   5.8.1-313
> serverb           MFEdx.x86_64    6.0.3-1021
> serverb           MFErt.i686      2.0-193
> serverb           McAfeeESP.x86_64        10.7.17-487
> serverb           McAfeeESPAac.x86_64     10.7.17-487
> serverb           McAfeeESPFileAccess.x86_64      10.7.17-487
> serverb           McAfeeFW.x86_64 10.7.17-50
> serverb           McAfeeRt.x86_64 10.7.17-487

How do I get what is unique to just servera?
I tried Highlight duplicates but it did not work as expected.

What columns did you work with when using Highlight Duplicate? Seems to me it would work if you limit it to columns B and C (Software and Version). How did you expect it to work?

I highlighted B and C and clicked Conditional Formatting>Highlight Cells Rules> Duplicate Values. I ended up with cells highlighted in one column or the other.

Try the following formula in conditional formatting: =SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A=$A1),--($B:$B = $B1))>1 (faster if you know how many rows in your table: =SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$10=$A1),--($B$1:$B$10 = $B1))>1)

That works. Can you explain what that formula is doing? I have over 33000 rows so when I try to sort Excel goes into Not Responding. Is there a way to speed it up?

Here is a formula you can use in Conditional Formatting:
It is much faster if you know how many rows are in your table and you use the following:
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$30000=$A1),--($B$1:$B$30000 = $B1))>1)

Here goes for a rough the explanation
On row 1: $A$1:$A$30000=$A1 will return true if the content of a given cell in A1:A30000 is equal to the value of cell A1, putting it in brackets and adding -- in front of it converts it from a boolean to a number (1 if true, 0 if false), same thing for column B. SUMPRODUCT will then multiply the two numbers of every row so if both are true, the result will be 1 otherwise it will be 0 and then add all of these together.
Since only rows where both booleans return true will result in a product equal to 1, the total sum is equal to a count of both conditions being true.
We know that the result cannot be less than 1 since the row we are currently evaluating will inevitably be included, so we ask to highlight any row whose sumproduct is greater than one.

Use this formula in Conditional Formatting
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B12&C2:C12,B13:B21&C13:C21,1,FALSE))

